# Installing Harrison Mixbus 32C-5

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install "harrison mixbus 32C-5" for Linux in Ubuntu 18.04. It is distributed as a "Mixbus32C-5.1.0-x86_64-gcc5.run" file. I use the "chmod +x Mixbus32C-5.1.0-x86_64-gcc5.run" instruction to convert and install it. Although the "ch mod ..." seems to pass ok, when I try to run the "Mixbus32C-5.1.0-x86_64-gcc5.run" in the terminal, I get the message "Can't open /home/elichord/Mixbus32C-5.1.0-x86_64-gcc5.run". In another computer that I tried, it worked pristinely. I don't know what the issue may be.
I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to run it as `./Mixbus32C-5.1.0-x86_64-gcc5.run` (note the ./ in front of the filename).